# Почему QAbstractTableModel и QTableView потребляют много оперативной памяти?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

необходимо отобразить в окне большое кол-во строк(от 1000 до 1М+). Для этого переопределяю QTableView и QAbstractTableModel, который заполняется данными из другого потока через сигнал-слоты (Qt::QueuedConection). Слот добавления строк выглядит следующим образом:

```
    void MaTableModel::insertRow_slot(QVector<QVector <QString>> &text)
    {
      beginResetModel();
      tableData.append(text);
      endResetModel();
    }
```

Реализация остальных необходимых функций тривиальна.

Всё вроде работает нормально(за исключением того что при использовании begin и endInsertRows() таблица отображает пустые строки), но приложение начинает потреблять большое кол-во оперативной памяти. К примеру если выполнить загрузку нескольких файлов суммарный объём занимаемой памяти которых равен 40МБ (220т строк), то потребляемая оперативная память программы увеличивается с 30Мб в стартовом состоянии, до 400мб. А если подгрузить ещё больше файлов то вообще падает с bad::alloc.

Вопрос в том нормально ли что так сильно увеличивается потребление памяти при использовании этих классов? Или я что то не так делаю?

Comment: ну вы бы хоть функцию `MaTableModel::append` привели, реализация хранилища для модели ведь на вас лежит, как она сделана?

Comment: Почитайте что делает beginResetModel https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel и какие процессы при этом происходят

Comment: @PavelGridin append это стандартная Qt-шная функция добавления в конец списка QVector::append. Контейнер для хранения данных в модели QVector<QVector<QString> >

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev читал, при использовании beginInsertRows таблица заполняется пустыми строками, а размер занимаемый приложением точно такой же как и при использовании beginResetModel

Comment: @qwerty12345, функции begin/end никак на размер не влияют, они просто уведомляют view об изменениях, разница между beginResetModel и beginInsertRows лишь в том, что при beginInsertRows будет вызвана меньшее число раз функция data()

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии уже не лезет, поэтому сюда...

Будем считать что упоминание про [beginInsertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows)/[endInsertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows) у вас приведено "просто так", и при работе с моделью не используются (по крайней мере код вы привели только слота добавления). История с ними несколько другая, но что касается вашего куска кода...

Для [beginResetModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) английским по белому написано - When a model is reset it means that **any previous data** reported from the model **is now invalid and has to be queried for again**. Т.е. `QTableView` оповещается что модель изменена и надо все пересчитывать заново.

Более правильным при обновлении является такое:

```
setUpdatesEnabled(false);
// крутим-вертим, добавляем-удаляем элементы модели
setUpdatesEnabled(true);
```

Когда [setUpdatesEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop) установлен в false, события `paint()` и `update()`  игнорируются, т.е. gui не приходится пересчитывать-перерисовывать изменения между снятием-установкой setUpdatesEnabled.

С полной уверенностью сказать не могу, но наиболее вероятно что beginResetModel/endResetModel приводит примерно к тому же эффекту, но после endResetModel приходится полностью пересчитывать-перерисовывать все с нуля

Comment: не персчитывать, а перерисовывать, т.е. после endResetModel из модели будут запрошены данные для всех ячеек, которые видны на экране, после же endInsertRows будут запрошены данные только для новых строк, это оптимизация для медленных моделей, а для быстрых в общем без разницы

Answer (score 0):

> необходимо отобразить в окне большое кол-во строк(от 1000 до 1М+)

Мне кажется, что по любому такое количество не поместится во вьюпорте QTableView. Это я к тому, что отрисовывается только видимая часть строк.

По мере прокрутки (скроллинг) дозагружаются из модели данных следующие строки (fetchMore что-то типа того).

А какая у вас модель данных QStandardItemModel или QSqlTableModel?

Comment: текст ответа (тем более на очень старый вопрос) — не самое подходящее место для уточняющих ворпосов.